# computer AND esp8266 WITH arduino

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266

how the bellow connection can be done , what the protocol that must be used to send bytes from computer through it's serial WiFi and receive the bytes in Arduino using ESP8266-01 WiFi Serial Transceiver Module.
[computer AND esp8266 WITH arduino](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6rC5.png)

Comment: Use the TCP protocol from pc to your esp: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol ... the esp will send the received data via serial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to accomplish, and what roles you want the computer and the arduino/esp combi to play. You can put the ESP in station or access point mode (or mixed), and have it talk to the arduino via the serial interface. The communication with the PC will indeed go via wifi/tcp protocol, but depending on your specific requirements you will have to decide one the roles. Then you can make the ESP a web client or a web server, mainly depending on the direction of the flow of information.
I assume you want to query the Arduino from the PC, in which you can send a HTTP/GET request from the PC to a simple web server on the ESP.
There are various examples in the Arduino examples that do just that to give you a start, available when you install the ESP library in the Arduino IDE, see: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino
HTH